# Is there a start/stop sequence in an image files binary data?

Tags: java, image

I am trying to build an image processor in Java and do not know much about the way that images are stored digitally. After doing just a bit of research I found out that there is more to the image than just the pixel data, there is also the meta data. So, is there a start/stop sequence I can check for when reading in the bytes of the image to know when the meta data has stopped and the actual pixel data that I'm after has started? I essentially want to be able to just write the pixel data to an array and exclude the meta data so I can manipulate the image directly without corrupting the meta data.

Btw, I know that there are plenty of image libraries for java, but I'm trying to build this from scratch using lower level implementations for practice/ out of curiosity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871028/how-to-write-a-jpeg-file-decoder-from-scratch does this help?

Comment: The metadata will contain the size of the following image somewhere, rather than start/stop sequences existing. You will need to implement decoders for all the image formats of interest to you. This is is a very large undertaking, and it is completetely redundant. Java contains some amazing image reading and image processing capabilities. I wrote a clock a few weeks ago and it only took a few hours. Last time I did this in the early 1990s it took a week.

Comment: That is highly dependent on the image format. Each one handles that differently so you have to implement it for every format you want to support.

Comment: While I understand that you like to implement things from scratch, to explore, learn and entertain your curiosity, you will need to narrow down your scope considerably to get anywhere. I've spent a considerable chunk of my spare time the last 15 years or so, implementing and maintaining [plugins for Java ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys). Originally, I wanted to create something like Photoshop in Java, but well.. There is only so much time. 